# Android keep data antenna alive

Tags: android

I have an app that requires the data transfer to be initiated instantly once a while, so I'd like to be able to keep the data antenna and wifi antenna alive (not sleep). I wonder:

1) does keeping the antennas on 24/7 kill device hardware much faster?
2) what's the best way to do this but not drain too much bandwidth (data service has only a few megabytes of bandwidth per month). eg. Ping my server every X seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keeping "antennas on" (you mean the cellular and WiFi interfaces) drains the battery horribly while in use. You need to write your app to avoid draining the battery continuously. If you are constantly accessing the net, then you are also chewing up the user's cellular data plan which is likely limited.

To be a good citizen, you need to ensure your app uses the network as little as possible. There are certainly a few ways to do this. The best way, I think, is to have an external server send a push notification to your app with data updates to avoid polling. It's somewhat complex to set up, but well worth it.

If you prefer to poll, there are several options.

You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set up a single or recurring alarms that triggers your network code whether your app is running or not. It keeps the network interface alive while you process code in your broadcast receiver's onReceive() method.

Alternatively you could implement a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that only operates while your app is running. Another way is to implement a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and post a Runnable task at a recurring interval.

I also much prefer [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki) which is extremely powerful but maybe overkill for what you are doing. With it you can set up a reactive sequence chain using interval observable to call your network code periodically.

You could acquire a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) on the interface while you are waiting for your request to return, but this is generally overkill and dangerous if you don't release it.

Sorry, I didn't provide examples since there are many options.